# Congruence inequality

Tags: number-theory, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $n>2$, by calculation or otherwise deduce that $5^{2^{n-3}} \neq -1 \pmod {2^n}$

Note:The problem arose when I tried to deduce $\langle5\rangle \cap \langle2^n-1\rangle=\{1\}$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{2^n}$, I have showed $\operatorname{ord}(5)=2^{n-2}$

Comment: Notice that if you write (mod 2^n) in LaTeX, it looks like this: $(mod 2^n)$; whereas if you write \pmod{2^n}, it looks like this: $\pmod{2^n}$.  Also, instead of $<5>$, you can write $\langle5\rangle$.  I did those and a couple of other $\TeX$ improvements.  Also you need backslashes in \{5\} in order to get this: $\{5\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to type "not congruent to"? I tried both "\not\equiv" and "\cancel\equiv" but neither works here.

Comment: a\not\equiv b $a\not\equiv b$.  Seems to work.  Is it possible that you typed a\not\equivb, with no space between \equiv and b?  If you do that, it sees "\equivb" rather than "\equiv" and then "b".

Comment: $a \not\equiv b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show by induction that if $n \ge 3$, then $5^{2^{n-3}}\equiv 1+2^{n-1}\pmod{2^n}$.  And it is clear that $1+2^{n-1}\not\equiv -1 \pmod{2^n}$ if $n \ge 3$.

The result holds when $n=3$. Now we do the induction step. Suppose that we know that for a certain $k$, we have $5^{2^{k-3}}\equiv 1+2^{k-1}\pmod{2^k}$.  We show that
$5^{2^{k-2}}\equiv 1+2^{k}\pmod{2^{k+1}}$.

By assumption, $5^{2^{k-3}}=1+2^{k-1} +t2^k$ for some integer $t$. Square both sides, and simplify modulo $2^{k+1}$. We get
$$5^{2^{k-2}}\equiv (1+2^{k-1})^2=1+2^k+2^{2k-2}\pmod{2^{k+1}}.$$
But $2^{2k-2}$ is divisible by $2^{k+1}$, since $2k-2 \ge k+1$ when $k \ge 3$. The result follows.